# Como controlar formulários MDI através de um método geral?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com formulários MDI. Tenho um menu que é o `MdiParent` e todos os demais ficam alocados como seus filhos.

Originalmente, o MDI permitia que eu abrisse o mesmo formulário diversas vezes; então eu passei a controlar a existência dos formulários através de uma declaração estática, dessa forma:

```cs
public static Form form1;
```

Na hora de abrir o formulário:

```cs
if (form1 != null)
{
    form1.Activate();
}
else
{
    form1 = new TED_Dados();
    form1.MdiParent = this;
    form1.Show();
}
```

E finalmente, quando eu fecho o formulário:

```cs
Menu.form1 = null;
```

Esse código é funcional, porém é necessário replicá-lo para todos os formulários, e eu preciso que todos estejam declarados no menu.
Gostaria de saber se há alguma solução que me permita controlar todos os formulários através de uma classe ou método únicos.

Comment: `Menu` é o quê? O form pai (MDI)?

Comment: Conselho que eu te dou para entender mais sobre isso: Crie um MDI à partir do template do Visual Studio, observe o código que é gerado. Já tem muita coisa pronta para trabalhar com os *Child* do MDI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem várias formas de resolver isso.

Uma abordagem que eu gosto é criar um método genérico para abrir os forms.

Neste caso, o método está no form MDI.

```
public void OpenForm<TForm>() where TForm : Form, new()
{
    var form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<TForm>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (form != null)
        form.BringToFront();
    else
        new TForm {MdiParent = this}.Show();
}
```

Veja um GIF do funcionamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Excelente solução, obrigado @LINQ! Seguindo ainda nessa linha, é possível também passar **parâmetros para um construtor** através desse método? Possuo um formulário que serve como cadastro e edição, e para o segundo caso preciso passar um ID. Estou passando um `int?` como parâmetro para a função `OpenForm` mas não consegui diferenciar a exibição do novo formulário para os dois casos.

Comment: @CaioPoschardt Aí vai depender um pouco da sua estruturação de código, se os parâmetros são sempre do mesmo tipo e tal. Sempre tem como fazer =D Se você tentar desenvolver a solução para este novo problema e não conseguir, abra uma nova pergunta para podermos tentar te ajudar